# Is BltFast supported in Windows Mobile DirectDraw?

Tags: windows-mobile, directdraw

Can I get access IDirectDrawSurface5 on a WindowsMobile device so that I can access the BltFast method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `IDirectDrawSurface5` interface in neither the [Windows Mobile 5.0 (and above) reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915187.aspx) nor in the `ddraw.h` header file of the Windows Mobile 6 SDK, nor is there a `BltFast` method. so no, you can not. you *can* use [`IDirectDrawSurface::Blt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911080.aspx), though.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I'm using Blt but just looking for a little more speed.

Answer (score 1):

For the fastest blits and direct screen access on Windows Mobile, I would recommend using: [PocketHal](http://www.droneship.com/wiki/index/)  or the library which is built on top of that: Pocketfrog

Comment: Thanks - I'm hoping to stick with DirectDraw, since I have that working, I'm looking for just a little more speed.  Ultimately PocketHal must use some sort of native API to render to the device.  Do you know what it uses?

Comment: It uses assembly, and has ways to get to the screenbuffer directly, where-as gdi, and even directx go through abstraction layers (and buffers), which ultimately make your app go a factor 1.5 - 4 times as slow (no hidden color conversions, bit rotations, etc).

Comment: So to emphasize the point: pockethal doesn't go through native API's...which makes it really fast.